# CSS vertical-align: text-top; not working for the span elements in my <p> tag?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

[image]

I want the top of any lower `span` tag attached to the base (bottom) of the an upper `span` tag, just like in the image.

I wanted to make the span elements align, so that the top of each span tag is at the base of an upper `span` tag. I tried using `vertical-align: text-top;` but I saw no changes.

```css
p#highlighter {
  border: 5px solid black;
  color: black;
  font-family: tusker-grotesk;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 2%;
}

p#highlighter span#pos {
  color: #DE000D;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p id="highlighter">
  <span id="pos">POS</span> <br />
  <span id="smaller">IS     AVAILABLE</span> <br />
  <span id="here">HERE</span>
</p>
```

I also tried `vertical-align: top;` but I still saw no changes.
My goal is that the `span` tags are vertically clustered (attached) to each other in the `p` container.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the "upper tag" that you'd like each span tag to be at the base of? Could you also clarify what you mean when you say you want "the `span` tags vertically clustered to each other"?

Comment: I meant the upper <span> tag.    For the clustering, I mean attached to each other vertically.

Comment: Can you draw and upload what you want to paint in paint, nothing is understood from what you say

Comment: They already seem to be attached to each other vertically, no?

Comment: Okay. I'll add a drawing.

Comment: I edited the question and also added an image. Please check to see if you understood the question.

Comment: does your use case specifically require the elements to be inline and not block level? bc this sort of precise text alignment is difficult w/ inline elements -  the whole point of them is that they should flow and adjust to the available space. For something like your picture, SVG text would probably be the best option

Comment: Yes, they must be inline. And I know nothing about SVG texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you right but if you just need something like on the picture, my snippet may help. It's mainly based on yours.

```css
#highlighter {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: black;
}

#highlighter span {
    font-size: 4em;
    line-height: 0.7;
}

#highlighter #pos {
    color: red;
}

#highlighter #smaller {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 0.15em;
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
}
```

```html
<p id="highlighter">
  <span id="pos">POS</span> <br />
  <span id="smaller">IS AVAILABLE</span><br />
  <span id="here">HERE</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Yeah! They're attached to as how I wanted it. But as I didn't get a quick answer, I used CSS positioning to make them align that way.